# I try to write a trigger that check the value if exists in table returns me a default value or a random value

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, duplicates

I try to write a trigger after insert ,checks my values if exists return me a default value or random one else insert users value in table.

```
alter trigger [dbo].[changevalues] 
on [dbo].[products]
after insert
as
begin
    declare @productname nvarchar(20), @productprice money

    select productname = @productname, price = @productprice
    from inserted

    if exists (select * from products 
               where productname like @productname and price = @productprice)
    begin 
        insert into products
        values ('fast', 100)
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into products
        values (@productname, @productprice)
    end
end
```

I expect that the code returns me ('fast', 100), but it return null in table

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Note also that an `AFTER` trigger, as the name implies, logically fires after rows are inserted. For an `AFTER` trigger to insert rows in the same table that it's defined on is quite unusual -- you will end up duplicating rows. You may have intended an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, or else you probably want to insert to another table. As for "returning" values, a trigger does not return rows to the caller (or at least it never should, as this can confuse clients that don't expect it). If you want that, you should write a stored procedure instead.

Comment: Apart from above, may be your code not working because of `productname like @productname and price = @productprice`

Answer (score 0):

The concept of this trigger seem wrong. Why would you create a trigger to insert data on the same table? 
If the data you just inserted exists in the table, why are you trying to insert it again?
Are you sure you want this?

You have a flaw in your query when checking the inserted values:

```
declare @productname nvarchar(20), @productprice money

select productname = @productname, price = @productprice
from inserted
```

It should be

```
select @productname = productname, @productprice = price
from inserted
```

This way you select the correct values from the inserted data.

Answer (score 0):

You want an `instead of` trigger, not an `after insert` trigger.  The logic should be more like this:

```
insert into products (productname, price)
    select (case when p.productname is null then i.productname else 'fast' end),
           (case when p.productname is null then i.price else 100 end)
    from inserted i outer apply
         (select top 1 p.*
          from products p
          where i.productname like p.productname and i.price = p.productprice
         ) p
```

As far as I can tell, this is non-sensical logic.  You will be getting multiple duplicate rows with the default values, and that doesn't make much sense.